# How to use a different Certificate for Service Fabric endpoints in local vs production?

Tags: cloud, ssl-certificate, local, azure-service-fabric

How would I use a local certificate while debugging my fabric in Visual Studio,
and automatically use the appropriate cloud certificate when deploying to production?

Currently I manually change the used certificate in the `ApplicationManifest.xml`:

`<EndpointBindingPolicy EndpointRef="GatewayTypeEndpoint" CertificateRef="example-local" />`
(Add/Remove `-local`)

However this is cumbersome and dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that this is not currently possible, and thus have opened a Feedback post at https://feedback.azure.com/forums/293901-service-fabric/suggestions/16935187-the-ability-to-specify-a-different-certificate-for

The workaround I ended up with is adding the following to `Deploy-FabricApplication.ps1`:

```
if ($PublishProfileFile.EndsWith("Cloud.xml")) {
   $file = "$ApplicationPackagePath\ApplicationManifest.xml";
   (Get-Content $file).replace('CertificateRef="example-local"', 'CertificateRef="example"') | Set-Content $file
}
```

after `$publishProfile = Read-PublishProfile $PublishProfileFile`